# Are all sugars detrimental to health when consumed in the quantity of common processed foods?

Tags: nutrition, sugar, glucose

Are fructose, glucose, and high fructose corn syrhop all damaging to health if consumed in portions common to processed foods?
I hope for some clarification on what types of sugars are not found in nature and which are synthetic and damaging to one's health and encourages fat cell development.

Comment: Wow, it's downvote city over here. Ok, so this question is a bit too general and makes incorrect assumptions. "Bad" is subjective and may be unproven in certain instances. HFCS is actually great for runners as I mention here: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/774/is-high-fructose-corn-syrup-bad-for-you
Additionally, we try to do one-post-one-question to keep things specific and clear. Try to narrow down what you're trying to ask, otherwise people will flag and downvote your post, possibly closing it down. Goodluck!

Comment: Deleted comments - Myself included, comments are for improving questions, not impugning others.

Comment: It's often said at least two servings of fruit and/or vegetables a day is part of a healthy diet. Does this involve a 'fair' amount of natural sugar?

Answer (score -1):

No sugar is harmful in moderation. Eating [too much sugar can be bad](http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/eating-too-much-added-sugar-increases-the-risk-of-dying-with-heart-disease-201402067021). There are several different [types of sugar](http://www.sugar.org/all-about-sugar/types-of-sugar/), though.

[Fructose is metabolized differently to sugar and glucose](http://foodwatch.com.au/blog/carbs-sugars-and-fibres/item/7-types-of-sugar-which-is-healthier.html), which some research suggests can be harmful [in massive doses](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2010/01/02/highfructose-corn-syrup-alters-human-metabolism.aspx)**, but when digested as part of your diet of fresh fruits and vegetables, it does not appear to cause problems (*Fructose natural occurs in fruit, which is how it gets its name*).

Comment: The downvote was probably because you don't cite many reputable sources. This site encourages using high-quality sources such as original research papers. If you could point to a few studies that suggest fructose can be harmful in massive doses, I'm sure you'll get plenty of upvotes.

Comment: Your source is a blog site run by someone who profits from "your chance to start enjoying [his] high-quality natural products." Also, the references he cites - which makes it appear that he's using science to back up his claims - are all self-references. **For profit medical websites are not trustworthy references.** Please either avoid using such sites as references, or clearly indicate that it is such a site.

Comment: @anongoodnurse one source of four, which everyone who is a smart as you can come to the same conclusion you did.

Comment: The OP asked, "Are fructose, glucose, and high fructose corn syrhop all damaging to health if consumed in portions common to processed foods?" Three references didn't address that. The OP is aware there are different sugars and is asking if, at "normal" levels, they are deleterious to health. Answers which are direct answers to the OP are generally regarded more favorably, as are answers with better references to support the main point.

Comment: @DaveL Where did you see that original research papers are necessarily high-quality sources?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to exclusively indicate that original would be high-quality. I mean that original would be more likely to have more empirically based information. Thanks for pointing that out, it's important to clarify.

Comment: -anongoodnurse makes excellent points..

Answer (score -4):

From what I've read, sugar is sugar is sugar.

Although natural occurring sugar might be somewhat less harmful to your body, the basic effects of sugar on the body, like for people with diabetes, are usually not different, no matter what form the sugar is in.

Quote from [6 Healthy Sugars That Can Kill You](http://authoritynutrition.com/6-healthy-sugars-that-can-kill-you/)

> “Sugar scares me.” – [Dr. Lewis Cantley, Cancer Researcher](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_C._Cantley)
>
> ....
>
> All the sugar you eat will go down to your intestine, get broken down into glucose and fructose and eventually reach the liver.
>
> Your liver does not know (or care) whether the sugar you eat is organic or not.

[Is sugar toxic?](http://mobile.nytimes.com/2011/04/17/magazine/mag-17Sugar-t.html?referrer=&_r=0) - Dr. Lustig

Comment: If you've read something, this site encourages you to cite it and make sure it's a reputable source, not a company-sponsored report or something. Since your answer doesn't cite anything and go into detail, it received downvotes. I hope you can improve this and don't get discouraged, it can be hard to write a good answer, but when you have credible sources and explain thoroughly, answering will feel and be rewarding. Also, those people who downvoted may come back and switch it to an upvote.

Comment: OK I've added sources

Comment: A lot of products list some ingrediants like sodium or cholesterol etc, and they give a % daily value on the back of the product ( or the front); this is in the Nutrition Facts part of the label. This % daily value is given for all the listed ingrediants EXCEPT sugar. Why is that?

Comment: The world health association said recently every one should limit there sugar intake to 5 grams of sugar a day or was it less?